# Spring cloud stream to send message to topics hosted on Confluent

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I have written a Spring cloud stream message producer which is successfully posting the payload to the topic on my local bootstrap server. I want to post the payload onto the topic that I have created on Confluent Cloud. What configuration changes do I need to make? Below is the configuration for localhost which is working.

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        output:
          destination: ordersTopic
          content-type: application/json
      kafka:
        binder:
          zkNodes: localhost
          brokers: localhost
      default-binder: kafka
```

Answer (score 0):

You no longer need `zkNodes` - modern Kafka clients only talk directly to the broker and don't talk to zookeeper. What version of spring-cloud-stream are you using? That property (zkNodes) is no longer present in recent versions.

You need to set the `brokers` property to match whatever is configured as the host/port of the advertised listeners in the broker's `server.properties` files.

Comment: How about the API Access key and Secret keys. Is there a document for connecting to Confluent.io. I am using 3.0.9.RELEASE version of spring-cloud-stream

Comment: That's outside of Spring's scope; sorry; we just delegate to the kafka-clients; refer to the Kafka and Confluent documentation.

Comment: I found some docs [here](https://docs.confluent.io/5.5.0/cloud/using/config-client.html) looks like you add them as properties; you can set arbitray Kafka properties via the `...kafka.binder.configuration` property; e.g. `...kafka.binder.configuration.foo.bar: baz`. There is also a `...jaas` property, in case you need that.